# How do you disable antialiasing on BoxDecoration?

Tags: flutter

I'm trying to make my own custom button in Flutter. When adding a BoxDecoration with a border, I noticed that there was antialiasing being applied to the border. How do you disable antialiasing?

```
class MyButton extends StatefulWidget {
    const MyButton({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

    @override
    _MyButtonState createState() => _MyButtonState();
}

class _MyButtonState extends State<MyButton> {
    @override
    Widget build(BuildContext context) {    
        return Container(
            padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 10.0, vertical: 2.0),
            decoration: const BoxDecoration(
                border: Border(
                    top: BorderSide(width: 5, color: Colors.grey),
                    left: BorderSide(width: 5, color: Colors.grey),
                    bottom: BorderSide(width: 5, color: Colors.grey),
                    right: BorderSide(width: 5, color: Colors.grey)
                ),
                color: Colors.blue,
            ),
            child: const Text('OK', textAlign: TextAlign.center, style: TextStyle(color: Colors.black)),
        );
    }
}
```

This is what the button looks like now:
[image: Now]

This is how it should look after:
[image: This is what the button should look like]

Comment: I couldn't work out a way to disable the AA on borders so hacked around it by removing the border and wrapping the widget I wanted a border on with a `Container` and `Padding`.